# One component is displayed twice in the page

Tags: aem, sightly

I have a requirement where the template should have pre-defined component in it. Once the page is created all these components should be moved or can be deleted.
Also it icludes a parsys.

This one I have completed. But I am facing one issue.
If I mention in my code as

```
<sly data-sly-resource="${'content' @ resourceType='wcm/foundation/components/parsys'}" data-sly-unwrap="true"></sly>
```

I am getting same component twice in the page.

If I mention something else in place of content it is working fine.

Could anyone please help me in this.

THe sample code which I am using.

```
<div class="sample1"><sly data-sly-resource="${'content/sample1' @ resourceType=''}" data-sly-unwrap/></div>

<div class="sample2"><sly data-sly-resource="${'content/sample2' @ resourceType=''}" data-sly-unwrap/></div>
<sly data-sly-resource="${'content' @ resourceType='wcm/foundation/components/parsys'}" data-sly-unwrap="true"></sly>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The components are likely showing up twice for the following reasons

1. Once from the `data-sly-resource="${'content/sample2' @ resourceType=''}"` call which includes them directly.
2. Once while rendering the `content` parsys. A parsys is a component type which renders all of it's children automatically.

If you're trying to set up which components exist on a page when it is first created I would look at using a [Template](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/the-basics/templates.html) instead.

---

**side notes**

- If you're using a `<sly></sly>` tag you don't need to include `data-sly-unwrap`. Sly tags automatically unwrap.
- Rather than having `<div><sly data-sly-resource="..."></sly></div>` you can put the `data-sly` attributes directly on the div: `<div class="sample2" data-sly-resource="${'content/sample2' @ resourceType=''}"></div>`

Comment: Thanks for the update. I was including the component resouce type in template creation and was data-sly-resource. Because of this, the component was loading twice. I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

The `'content'` part is actually used as `@path` parameter which means that a resource named `content` will be included using the given `@resourceType`.

You have probably put twice this include in your component which resulted in components put in that parsys showing twice.

Each parsys has to have it's own unique path.

```
<!--first parsys-->
<sly data-sly-resource="${@path = 'content1', 
    @resourceType='wcm/foundation/components/parsys'}" data-sly-unwrap="true"></sly>

<!--second parsys-->
<sly data-sly-resource="${@path = 'content2',
    @resourceType='wcm/foundation/components/parsys'}" data-sly-unwrap="true"></sly>
```

Comment: I have added a small sample code which we used. I don't mention content twice. Here we have many component and only for one component I am facing this issue.

Comment: @NaveenSakhare are you saying this did not answer you question? If so, it appears you accidentally accepted this answer even though it doesn't answer your question